# How can I know when 'str' will be able to handle unicode, and when it won't?

Tags: python, unicode

Why does the `str` operator able to convert a list of unicode objects to a `str` object, but not able to convert a single unicode object?

For example, in the code below I'm creating a list of unicode objects, and then attempting to print out that list. In the second print statement, I'm just printing out a single unicode object.

```
bill = []
bill.append(u'的东西')
bill.append(u'的东西')

print("list is " + str(bill)) # this is OK
print ("this string is " + str(u'的东西')) # generates a UnicodeEncodeError
```

The first print statement results in:

```
list is [u'\u7684\u4e1c\u897f', u'\u7684\u4e1c\u897f']
```

But the second:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can see that in the first statement, the actual unicode objects are being printed, and not converted using any codec - why can't this be done for the single object?

Comment: You are looking for the `repr()` function; lists don't have direct support for `str()`, and the default fallback is to produce the output for `repr()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr); lists don't have direct support for `str()`, and the default fallback is to produce the output for `repr()` instead.

`repr()` will always produce ASCII-safe output for built-in types:

```
>>> bill = [u'的东西', u'的东西']
>>> print repr(bill[0])
u'\u7684\u4e1c\u897f'
```

For built-in containers such as `list`, `tuple`, `dict` and `set`, the contents are always represented with their `repr()` content, recursively.

Note that `repr()` is aimed at producing *debug output*, not user-readable output. Stick to using Unicode in your code everywhere if you need to handle *text*, decode when ingesting (unless the API you use already decodes for you), encode when producing output (again, unless the API already encodes, like `print` will). I strongly recommend you read / watch [*Pragmatic Unicode* by Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) to understand Python and Unicode better.

Comment: @patchwork: what are you trying to achieve? Produce debugging output or user-readable output? If the latter, work with `unicode` exclusively, and only convert to `str` with explicit `unicode.encode()` calls where needed (such as sending it to a network socket).

Comment: yes - user-readable output. I call `encode()` before sending over a network. But have been also calling `encode()` when trying to print but it seems like a bad idea (or just less readable).